# Avoid out of bounds exception in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to solve a problem which uses a 2D array, the problem of a rat in a maze.

While checking the conditions trying to compile, it finds an Array index out of bounds exception... how can I check the values so it doesn't go out of the array bounds?

```
static void solveMaze(){

    int nSteps = 0; // Number of steps.
    int x = 0; int y = 0; // Starting point.

    boolean mazeCompleted = false;

    while (!mazeCompleted){

        if(x == maze.mazeMatrix.length && y == maze.mazeMatrix.length)
            mazeCompleted = true;

        else if(maze.mazeMatrix[x+1][y] == 0){ // Move right.
            maze.mazeMatrix[x+1][y] = 2;
            x++; nSteps++;
        }

        else if(maze.mazeMatrix[x-1][y] == 0){ // Move left.
            maze.mazeMatrix[x-1][y] = 2;
            x--; nSteps++;
        }

        else if(maze.mazeMatrix[x][y+1] == 0){ // Move down.
            maze.mazeMatrix[x][y+1] = 2;
            y++; nSteps++;
        }

        else if(maze.mazeMatrix[x][y-1] == 0){ // Move up.
            maze.mazeMatrix[x][y-1] = 2;
            y--; nSteps++;
        }

    }

    maze.printMatrix();
    System.out.println("Maze COMPLETE! - With a total of " + nSteps + " steps.");

}
```

Tried before with two "for" loops to prevent the out of bounds but I just can't go diagonal in this problem.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: Easiest way would be to use 2 for loops actually. Otherwise you can just check before incrementing / decrementing if the value will be valid. eg: if(x-- > 0){x--;}

Comment: When x is zero, you try to access x-1, as an example. You need to check x and you against zero and the max size of the maze, *before* trying to access a neighboring cell.

Comment: @Dylan do you mean to decrement x twice in your example?

Comment: No sorry, that was a mistake by typing to quickly :P if(x>0){x--;} is what I meant :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a pretty crucial bug in your program. You will never reach the end of the maze!

```
if(x == maze.mazeMatrix.length && y == maze.mazeMatrix.length)
```

references indices that are out of bounds! It should be

```
if(x == maze.mazeMatrix.length - 1 && y == maze.mazeMatrix.length - 1)
```

You also need to check to see whether you can & should move before you try to move there. I.E. :

```
while (!mazeCompleted){

boolean moveRight = (x + 1 < mazeMatrix.length && maze.mazeMatrix[x+1][y] == 0 ? true : false);
boolean moveLeft = (x - 1 >= 0 && maze.mazeMatrix[x-1][y] == 0 ? true : false);
boolean moveUp = (y + 1 < mazeMatrix[x].length && maze.mazeMatrix[x][y+1] == 0 ? true : false);
boolean moveDown = (y - 1 >= 0 && maze.mazeMatrix[x][y-1] == 0 ? true : false);
```

And:

```
else if(moveRight) { // Move right.
        maze.mazeMatrix[x+1][y] = 2;
        x++; nSteps++;
}
```

etc. Although it does seem like this is something that should be solved recursively, as if there are any loops in the maze you will end up getting stuck and infinite looping.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) ! Yes, the problem should be solved using backtracking, but it can be also solved recursively can't it?

Comment: The problem should be solved using backtracking. Your algorithm doesn't backtrack at all. Using recursion will allow you to backtrack.